# What is the computational complexity of `itertools.combinations` in python?

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory

`itertools.combinations` in python is a powerful tool for finding all combination of *r* terms, however, I want to know about its **computational complexity**.

Let's say I want to know the complexity in terms of *n* and *r*, and certainly it will give me all the *r* terms combination from a list of *n* terms.

According to the Official document, this is the rough implementation.

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: It's gonna be nCr, i.e O(n choose r)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There is going to be at least another factor r for the tuple generation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say it is `θ[r (n choose r)]`, the `n choose r` part is the number of times the generator has to `yield` and also the number of times the outer `while` iterates.

In each iteration at least the output tuple of length `r` needs to be generated, which gives the additional factor `r`. The other inner loops will be `O(r)` per outer iteration as well.

This is assuming that the tuple generation is actually `O(r)` and that the list get/set are indeed `O(1)` at least on average given the particular access pattern in the algorithm. If this is not the case, then still `Ω[r (n choose r)]` though.

As usual in this kind of analysis I assumed all integer operations to be `O(1)` even if their size is not bounded.

Comment: Great work; question, for `n=4; r=2; -> O(12)`, should that still be assumed as `O(1)`?

Comment: @KenanNo, because the equation is dependent on n and r. For example, when you iterate on a list, the runtime is O(n). Because it's dependent on `n`, where n is the size of the list.
Now, if a hypothetical list size is 12 (i.e n= 12) that does not mean the runtime is O(1). Because as soon as you run your algorithm on a list of size 100000 the runtime will increase.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same question too (For itertools.permutations) and had a hard time tracing the complexities. 
This led me to visualize the code using matplotlib.pyplot;

The code snippet is shown below

```
result=[]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
x=list(range(1,11))
def permutations(iterable, r=None): 
    count=0
    global result
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            count+=1
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            resulte.append(count)
            return
for j in x:
    for i in permutations(range(j)):
        continue

x=list(range(1,11))
plt.plot(x,result)
```

[Time Complexity graph for itertools.permutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpOSq.png)

From the graph, it is observed that the time complexity is O(n!) where n=Input Size

Comment: The time complexity is not O(n!); it should be O(n! * n). Plotting a graph can't tell you the time complexity; it can only give you clues.