# How many sub-sequences of unique elements can be possible?

Tags: python, math, subsequence

I'v a sequence of integer number `[A1, A2, A3.....AN]`
I'm trying to count all sub-sequences which contain at most K unique numbers.

### For Example:

Given sequence:: `[2, 3, 3, 7, 5]`  and `K = 3`

All sub-sequences are:

```
[],
[2],[3],[3],[7],[5],
[2, 3],[2, 3],[2, 7],[2, 5],[3, 3],[3, 7],[3, 5],[3, 7],[3, 5],[7, 5],
[2, 3, 3],[2, 3, 7],[2, 3, 5],[2, 3, 7],[2, 3, 5],[2, 7, 5],[3, 3, 7],[3, 3, 5],[3, 7, 5],[3, 7, 5],
[2, 3, 3, 7],[2, 3, 3, 5],[2, 3, 7, 5],[2, 3, 7, 5],[3, 3, 7, 5],
[2, 3, 3, 7, 5]
```

**I need all sub-sequences (only for counting) that have unique elements.**

### Counted sub-sequences are:

```
[],
[2],[3],[3],[7],[5],
[2, 3],[2, 3],[2, 7],[2, 5],[3, 7],[3, 5],[3, 7],[3, 5],[7, 5],
[2, 3, 7],[2, 3, 5],[2, 3, 7],[2, 3, 5],[2, 7, 5],[3, 7, 5],[3, 7, 5]
```

Total = 22

### Not counted sub-sequences are:

```
[3, 3],
[2, 3, 3],[3, 3, 7],[3, 3, 5]
```

Ignored for higher length: `length > K` (If `k = 5` then ignored for duplicate elements):

```
[2, 3, 3, 7],[2, 3, 3, 5],[3, 3, 7, 5],
[2, 3, 3, 7, 5]
```

**[ N.B:** All sub-sequences not be unique, but their elements (number) should be identical. Ex- [2, 3],[2, 3] both are counted but [3, 3] ignored **]**

### ::CODE::

```py
import itertools as it
import sys, math

n, m = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
a = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

cnt = 0
for i in range(2, m+1): 
  for val in it.combinations(a, i):
    if len(set(val)) == i:
      cnt += 1
print(1+n+cnt)
```

Input:

```
5 3
2 3 3 7 5
```

Output: `22`

**BUT** I need a **efficient solution**, maybe mathematical solution using `nCr`etc or programmatic solution.

#### Constraints:

```
1 <= K <= N <= 1,000,00
1 <= Ai <= 9,000
```

**Time:** `1 sec`

Comment: "gimme some code" is not a question and i didnt see any other relevance of the c++ tag, so i removed it

Comment: I would transform `[2, 3, 3, 7, 5]` into `{2:1, 3:2, 7:1, 5:1}`, then for each combination with keys, you multiply with corresponding value.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you please explain more?

Comment: @CeliusStingher : emojis are not for influencing but for visually describing.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Sounds good.

Comment: The amount of subsequences (with no repetition) of size `k` from a sequence of size `n` is `n * (n-1) *...* (n-k+1) / k!` (`n! / k! (n-k)!`). May it can help.

Comment: With your current solution, your construct `[2, 3],[2, 3]`, whereas I propose to construct `[2, 3]` only once, but count it with the weight of the dictionary.

Comment: @dcg It's count all distinct sub-sequences which contains duplicate element. 

But I have to ignore some sub-sequences which contains duplicate items. Anyway, how can i count all ignored sub-sequences??

Comment: @AfrinMouDia you could get how many elements are distinct with `len(set(list))`

Comment: @Jarod42 Umm, but another problems, how could I track/count sub-sequences which have that elements, Ex- How many sub-sequences ```2``` have (so that I can multiply it with the dict value)??

Comment: @dcg if so then **TLE**, Do you mean another way? if so, please explain more.

Comment: @AfrinMouDia: `cnt += 1` becomes `cnt += functools.reduce(lambda acc, k: acc * val[k], val, 1)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Please check out the **Constraints** If i need to generate sub-sequences then it can't be done within `1 seconds`

Comment: @AfrinMouDia Is it mandatory that the sub-sequences have to be obtain from the inputted sequence, i.e., you cannot remove repeated elements before computation? If so, I don't see a way of getting what you want if it isn't by construction (as you're doing). I gave you the formula to get the number of sub-sequences of size `k` from a sequence of size `n` (which is the number of combinations you get from `it.combinations(a, k)`).

Comment: @dcg Yes, Its mandatory  that the sub-sequences have to be obtain from the inputted sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import numpy as np
mod = 1000000007
n, k = map(int, input().split())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
fre = [0]*10000
A = []
for i in range(0, n):
    fre[a[i]] += 1
for i in range(0, 9001):
    if fre[i] > 0:
        A.append(fre[i])   
kk = min( len( A ), k ) + 1
S = np.zeros( kk, dtype=int );   S[0] = 1
for a in A:
   S[1:kk] = (S[1:kk] + (a * S[0:kk-1])% mod) % mod
ans = 0
for s in S:
    ans = ((ans + s) % mod)
print(ans)
```

This program return all sub-sequences (only for count) that have unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import itertools 

def findsubsets(s, n): 
    return list(itertools.combinations(s, n))

my_list = [2, 3, 3, 7, 5]
list_len = 0

for i in range(1,len(my_list)):
    list_len += len(set(findsubsets(my_list, i)))

print(list_len)
```

output:

```
22
```

**edit:**
remove permutations with same numbers from list:

```
import itertools 

def findsubsets(s, n): 
    return list(list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(s, n))

my_list = [2, 3, 7, 5, 3]
list_len = 0

for i in range(1,len(my_list)):
    list_len += len(set(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in findsubsets(my_list, i)))

print(list_len)
```

output:

```
22
```

Comment: Efficiency does not changed.
Also, for the input ```2 3 7 5 3``` The output ```28```

Comment: @AfrinMouDia you right! now I remove permutations with same numbers! ;)

Comment: Its not really what i want. I need to remove itertools.combinations(), otherwise **TLE**. Please check out the constraints and time limit.

Comment: @AfrinMouDia hmmm ... look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419536/what-is-the-computational-complexity-of-itertools-combinations-in-python

Comment: Yes, that's why i need to compute(count) the number without generating sub-sequences.