# How to find sum of every possible trio in a given array in O(n^2)?

Tags: arrays, loops

I have an array like this:

1,2,3,4,5.

I want to find sum of every possible trio like:
123, 124, 125, 134, 135, etc

I have tried using 3 while loops and 3 variables(i, j, k) to iterate over every trio, but the time complexity
was O(n^3), and I want in O(n^2).

Hope someone will help.

Answer (score 0):

`k-permutations of n` ? My first try would be something like this, given the fact that the array is like `[1,2,3,...,n,n+1]` and `sums of 3` will repeat:

```py
unique_sums = set()

iter_counter = [0]
call_counter = [0]
def sum_permute(arr, perm, k):
    call_counter[0] += 1
    result = sum(perm)
    if result in unique_sums:
        return
    if len(perm) == k:
        iter_counter[0] += 1
        # print(f"sum{perm}={result}")
        unique_sums.add(result)
        return
    for el in arr:
        iter_counter[0] += 1
        if el not in perm:
            perm.add(el)
            sum_permute(arr, perm, k)
            perm.pop()
```

If don't discard repeaded sums, this runs in `n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1), k=3`, `~O(n^3)`, assuming `lookup in set` be `O(1)`. Anyway here is a result:

```py
arr = [el for el in range(100)]
sum_permute(arr ,set(), 3)
print(f"Total elements: {len(arr)}")
print(f"Total iterations: {iter_counter[0]}")
print(f"Total function call: {call_counter[0]}")
print(f"n^2={len(arr)}^2={len(arr)**2}")
```

Result:

```sh
Total elements: 100
Total iterations: 3372
Total function call: 3091
n^2=100^2=10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Python got a build-in method to do it.

time complex:[What is the computational complexity of `itertools.combinations` in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419536/what-is-the-computational-complexity-of-itertools-combinations-in-python)

code:

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.combinations(range(1,6),3)))
```

result:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
```

if you need sum

code:

```
import itertools
print(sum([int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in list(itertools.combinations(range(1,6),3))]))
```

result:

```
1845
```