# Fastest approach for performing operations on all possible combinations

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for fastest approach to get min absoulute difference between all possible pair combination from a list.

I did two solutions but none is acceptable for time duration.

```
arr = [x for x in range(10000)]
minAbsDiff1(arr)
minAbsDiff2(arr)

def absDiff(elem):
    return abs(elem[0]-elem[1])

# first solution takes 5.96 sec
def minAbsDiff1(arr):
    seq = itertools.combinations(arr, 2)
    m = min(seq, key=absDiff)
return absDiff(m)

# second solution takes 6.96 sec
def minAbsDiff2(arr):
    seq = itertools.combinations(arr, 2)
    test = [abs(tup[0]-tup[1]) for tup in seq]
return min(test)
```

Input example:
[3, -7, 0]

All combinations:
(3, -7), (3, 0), (-7, 0)

Output min abs diff: 3

Explanation: 3 - 0 = 3

Comment: `minAbsDiff1` is probably the fastest you'll get.

Comment: You could use a different language, like C, but note, if `arr` is expected to grow, you'll quickly get back to this very same situation. This is the problem with [brute forcing a combinatorial problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)

Comment: Why not sorting the array O(n logn) and then performing a linear search between neighbors O(n) ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: very pessimistic opinion.

Comment: Using the itertools sledgehammer to generate all pairs is a terrible sin !

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, my comments were in reference to relying on a brute-force solution to the general case of "performing operations on all possible combinations". If the specific case lets you take advantage of something to improve the solution, then yes, that will be meaningfully faster

Comment: It is a sin for many reasons. In particular the space complexity is tremendous. Use a double loop !

Comment: Sorting the array will not make a difference because 'combinations' call will sort them afterwards also calling combinations is returning tuples pairs and it's taking very small amount of time comparing with finding the min.

Comment: What ??? Take the time to benchmark this !

Comment: I'm not saying that is not quicker, I'm saying that is not the case since combination call is sorting them anyway but not with the rule that I'm wanting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solutions

Another possible way that might give you a faster result:

Sorting the values first and iterating over them to find the min difference:

```py
def minAbsDiffSorted(arr):
    sorted_arr = sorted(arr)
    min_val = sorted_arr[-1] - sorted_arr[0]
    for i, j in zip(sorted_arr[:-1], sorted_arr[1:]):
        min_val = min(min_val, j - i)
    return min_val
```

Doing the same with numpy is even faster:

```py
import numpy as np
def minAbsDiffNumpy(arr):
    return np.diff(np.sort(np.array(arr))).min()
```

## Mechanism

Array to process:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
arr = np.array([random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(20)])
>>>
array([55, 76, 88,  2, 68,  9, 24, 50, 15, 86, 19, 31, 80, 39, 14, 48, 32,
       32, 35, 26])
```

Let's sort the array:

```py
arr = np.sort(arr)
>>>
array([ 2,  9, 14, 15, 19, 24, 26, 31, 32, 32, 35, 39, 48, 50, 55, 68, 76,
       80, 86, 88])
```

Get the differences between the values:

```py
np.diff(arr)
>>>
array([ 7,  5,  1,  4,  5,  2,  5,  1,  0,  3,  4,  9,  2,  5, 13,  8,  4,
        6,  2])
```

You take the minimum of these differences, which, in this case, is 0. This is equivalent to the minimal distance of the pair-wise combinations of the original array.

## Times

Here are the respective times on my machine:

```
%%timeit
minAbsDiff1(arr)
17.3 s ± 438 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
minAbsDiff2(arr)
19.1 s ± 1.16 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
minAbsDiffSorted(arr)
7.85 ms ± 498 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
minAbsDiffNumpy(arr)
444 µs ± 3.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

## Explanation

For the reasons behind it, see @Yves Daoust detailed explanations.

Yes, using combinations might also sort the results. However, there the dominant operation is not sorting but making the combinations themselves.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422646/7648578) you can read more about `itertools.combinations` time complexity.

Compared to that, here the most expensive operation is the sorting and that's it.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood the requirement.  I wrote an exmple in the desciption.

Comment: I updated the answer. Does this clarify it?

Comment: Cannot use numpy as it is an external python lib, the exercise should be with built in libraries.

Comment: `minAbsDiffSorted` does not use numpy.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the elements increasingly, the closest to every element is either the immediate previous or the immediate next. Hence it suffices to try every consecutive pairs.

Doing so, you trade O(n²) complexity for O(n), a significant improvement. Sorting will take O(n log n) and dominate the cost (still better than O(n²)), unless your data allows non-comparison-based sorting.

Comment: Sorting the array will not make a difference because 'combinations' call will sort them afterwards.

Comment: @cristian: I am afraid you understood nothing of my post.

Comment: @cristian several people here are trying patiently to explain to you how to find the best pair without having to examine all pairs. Take a moment and try your best to understand what’s being said.

Comment: I knew that from the start that I sould find a solution to improve it. but none so far was given. so what I supose to do ...give pety thumps up just for trying ? I have receive enugh thumps down from 'smart'  people ;)