# Is complexity of Itertools.Combinations_with_replacement() the same of Itertools.Combination()?

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Complexity of Itertools.Combination() is `θ[r (n choose r)]` according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422646/17598488.

The implementation of Combinations_with_replacement() is :

```
def combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    # combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if not n and r:
        return
    indices = [0] * r
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i:] = [indices[i] + 1] * (r - i)
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Answer (score 2):

When choosing `r` items out of `n` total items *with* replacement, the amount of possible combinations is given by `(n + r - 1)! / (r! * (n - 1)!)`, which is equal to `(n + r - 1) choose r`.

So that is the amount of tuples which is created. As we can see, creation of each tuple requires looping over `r` indices, so tuple creation is `O(r)`.

I believe the update `indices[i:] = [indices[i] + 1] * (r - i)` is `O(r)`. Note that `i <= r`. Hence, the length of the right hand side is `<= r`. I am assuming that the update is done in place and can be done in `O(r)` time.

What then remains to be analyzed is the inner `for` loop. This loop is `O(r)`, since it is looping over a collection of length `r`.

Hence, given that the operations in the body of the `while` loop have complexity `O(r)` and that we have to execute that body `(n + r - 1) choose r` times, we can say that the time complexity of the entire function is `O(r * ((n + r - 1) choose r))`.